# How to poll a local file and showing a div with jQuery based on result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

So I made a script in php that returns "on" or "off" to tell me whether or not a shoutcast radio server is running or not... check.php

when it returns "on", i want to show a #online otherwise, I want to show #offline.

the check.php can just be polled once a minute.. can someone explain how to go about this? I've searched and searched and couldn't find an example. the check.php has very low overhead as it caches the result for 60 seconds at a time.

Comment: Show `#online` where exactly, and how, this is not very clear ?

Comment: a div id called online, I want to show a div if the remote file says on or off.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your needs:

```
function checkStatus(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'check.php',
    data: request, 
    // here `request` is any data you want to send to the server, 
    // like a radio station name perhaps, 
    // or omit this if your php page exists only to respond to this simple call
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(response) {
      var $online=$('#online').hide(); 
      var $offline=$('#offline').hide(); 
      if(response=="on") $online.show();
      else $offline.show();
      setTimeout(function(){ checkStatus(); }, 60000); //re-call every 60 seconds
    },
    error: function(){
        // handle error here
      setTimeout(function(){ checkStatus(); }, 60000); //re-call every 60 seconds or do something else here
    }
  });
}
checkStatus(); // call on load
```

Comment: it's not working, the console shows that request is not defined.

Comment: @MarcPope Please see the comment I've added to the code